# Implementing a queue using state pattern in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, state

I am trying to learn the state design pattern and one of the exercises provided by my teacher is to implement a queue, can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? No-one can help you if you don't show some effort on what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

The state design pattern is of the behavioral family and allows objects to alter their behavior depending on their internal state.

There are numerous examples of the state pattern in the Web, you can check for example [this](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

For implementing a queue using the state pattern, you have to think what states a queue could have (e.g., empty, full, etc) and how the behavior of its actions (e.g., enqueue, dequeue, peek, etc.) would change based on the state.

You could also check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/dsa_queue.htm) for more info about queue data structures.

If you play around a bit and have problems, copy some code and we 'll work on it.